# Anything wrong with this query? It's returning one result twice, I can't figure out why

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got this query, which searches for auctioneers by name, getting data from more than one table.

It's returning on result twice, even though it's using "distinct", but I can't figure out what's going on...

It'd be difficult to offer a sample of data, but I'm hoping some SQL genius can offer suggestions to possible causes...

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id,a.name, al.city
FROM auctioneers a
LEFT JOIN auctioneersloc al ON al.auctioneerId = a.id
LEFT JOIN auctioneerscont ac ON ac.auctioneerId = a.id
WHERE a.name LIKE "%Jones%"
GROUP BY city
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you `GROUP`ing but not doing any aggregation?

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that by "twice" you mean not the entire combination of (a.id, a.name, al.city) but just (a.id, a.name). That is entirely possible because the query is wrong in so many ways. It groups by City, and in each City, you will get a *RANDOM* id and name. DISTINCT works on ALL the columns, so if the (a.id,a.name) exists in multiple cities, you can get it twice.

Comment: Why are you joining to auctioneerscont at all? You aren't selecting from it and it's not in your where your group by clauses...

Comment: @Richard : should convert to an answer, the query is very wrong by trying to mix the MySQL-ism for allowing non-aggregated fields in a group by clause with a distinct.

Comment: @JNK typically it is OK to use a group by with no aggregation, but usually *only* if you don't also use a DISTINCT!

Comment: @NWest Only in `MySQL` - other RDBMS won't even allow such silliness.

Comment: @JNK Oracle allows it too. `select owner from dba_tables group by owner`

Comment: @NWest - they all allow it in that scenario - you don't have any ungrouped or unaggregated fields.  Only MySQL (afaik) allows `SELECT stuff, stuff2 from table group by stuff`

Comment: @JNK Ah, I see. Agreed, very silly.

Comment: @NWest - yep.  It returns a random value for  the ungrouped/aggregated fields, which can be very confusing

Comment: Hi, Guys. It's a pretty bad query I understand, but the entire where clause is built dynamically so it's not always just as in the example. I just wanted advice as to why I might have the extra duplicate result, and what I might do about it... Thanks.

Comment: @i-CONICA well, have you read my comment?

Comment: Hi, Richard. Yes I've read your comment, thanks. It is an entire duplicate, all a.id, a.name and al. city is being brought out twice, but not one after the other, there are several other results in between, but I can't recognise a pattern of any kind.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if you have duplicating `al.auctioneerId` or `ac.auctioneerId` in appropriate tables - you'll be getting one the same record from `auctioneers` returned per each id match.